# From for loop and if conditions to Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've to read a file containing some START and STOP times. The file is shaped as 2 columns: the first can have values 1 (meaning START) or 2 (meaning STOP), the second column contains the time values. I've to make an array where I have all the differences between consecutive START and STOP times. I've achieved this using a for loop and if statements. I am wondering if there is a way to do this also with some Numpy functions.

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    diff = []
    data = np.fromfile('file.dat', sep=" ").reshape((-1, 2))
    for obj in data:
        if obj[0] == 1:
            tmp = obj[1]
        if obj[0] == 2:
            diff.append(obj[1] - tmp)
```

If more consecutive 2 appear, I want the script to create as many diff-elements as the consecutive 2, considering for all of them the same START (the last 1 found). If more consecutive 1 appear, I want the script to skip until the last 1 of them, ignoring the others.

Answer (score 2):

Often the complications of using numpy arrays for this type of calculation isn't really worth it.  The code in the question is probably much easier to understand.  But...

```
import numpy as np

# *********** Generate some data ***************
            
np.random.seed( 2345 )

code = np.random.randint( 1, 3, size = 10 )

code
# array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

time = np.random.rand( 10 ) * 3.0
time = time.cumsum()
time
# array([ 1.91045539,  2.42703695,  3.20819455,  5.95415453,  7.34260105,
#         7.70317392, 10.34583043, 11.02448729, 13.45880826, 14.79644502])

# **********************************************

# Calculation
diff = np.zeros( 10 )
diff[ code == 1 ] = np.diff( time[ code == 1 ], prepend = 0 )
# Take differences between consecutive items where the code is 1

diff
# array([1.91045539, 0.        , 1.29773916, 2.74595997, 1.38844653,
#        0.        , 0.        , 3.68188623, 2.43432098, 1.33763676])

base = diff.cumsum()  # Cumulate that result
base
# array([ 1.91045539,  1.91045539,  3.20819455,  5.95415453,  7.34260105,
#         7.34260105,  7.34260105, 11.02448729, 13.45880826, 14.79644502]

(time - base)[ code == 2 ]
# array([0.51658156, 0.36057286, 3.00322938])
# Subtract the base from time and report where code == 2
```